# Closure Compiler: sorting dependencies with WHITESPACE_ONLY

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

## Situation

I'm using the example files from the Closure Compiler wiki article ["Manage Closure Dependencies: Using Closure Compiler to auto-sort files"](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies#using-closure-compiler-to-auto-sort-files):

```
icecream.js:
    goog.provide('ice.cream');

cone.js:
    goog.provide('waffle.cone');

shop.js:
    goog.provide('ice.cream.Shop');
    goog.require('ice.cream');
    goog.require('waffle.cone');
```

If I pass the files "out of order" to the compiler, and use the `SIMPLE` level:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js \
    --compilation_level SIMPLE \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT
```

then the compiler auto-sorts the files into dependency order before compiling them:

```
var ice = {cream:{}};
var waffle = {cone:{}};
ice.cream.Shop = {};
```

## Question

I'd like to use the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` level:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js \
    --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT
```

but then the files are *not* sorted:

```
goog.provide("ice.cream.Shop");
goog.require("ice.cream");
goog.require("waffle.cone");
goog.provide("ice.cream");
goog.provide("waffle.cone");
```

and so a run-time error occurs:

```
goog.require could not find: ice.cream
```

What CLI option(s) can I pass to the compiler to make it auto-sort the files when using the `WHITESPACE_ONLY` level?

## What I've tried

#### --closure_entry_point

I know that the `--closure_entry_point` option makes the compiler auto-sort the files:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js \
    --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
    --closure_entry_point 'ice.cream.Shop'
```

```
goog.provide("ice.cream");
goog.provide("waffle.cone");
goog.provide("ice.cream.Shop");
goog.require("ice.cream");
goog.require("waffle.cone");
```

But I don't want to have to specify a `--closure_entry_point`. I'd like a generic CLI command which doesn't require knowledge of the contents of the JavaScript source files being compiled.

#### --manage_closure_dependencies

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js \
    --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT \
    --manage_closure_dependencies
```

This does [enable dependency sorting](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/AbstractCommandLineRunner.java#L237), but unfortunately it also [enables dependency pruning](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/AbstractCommandLineRunner.java#L236). So all the files are removed, and the compiler's output is empty.

The [docs](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java#L448) for this option:

> Automatically sort dependencies so that a file that `goog.provide`s symbol `X` will always come before a file that `goog.require`s symbol `X`.
>
> If an input provides symbols, and those symbols are never required, then that input will not be included in the compilation.

#### Modifying the compiler's source code

In the [`CompilationLevel`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java) class, I've tried modifying the [`applyBasicCompilationOptions()`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java#L81) method ([used for `WHITESPACE_ONLY`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/v20150505/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CompilationLevel.java#L55)) to enable dependency sorting:

```java
private static void applyBasicCompilationOptions(CompilerOptions options) {
    options.skipAllCompilerPasses();
    options.dependencyOptions.setDependencySorting(true);  // Added this line
}
```

Now, with this command:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js shop.js --js icecream.js --js cone.js \
    --compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY \
    --formatting PRETTY_PRINT
```

the files are auto-sorted:

```
goog.provide("ice.cream");
goog.provide("waffle.cone");
goog.provide("ice.cream.Shop");
goog.require("ice.cream");
goog.require("waffle.cone");
```

But I'd rather not have to modify the compiler's source code.

#### Using the Java API

I know I could [call the compiler from the Java API](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-call-closure-compiler-from-the-java-api), but I'd prefer a CLI solution.